# matplotlib imshow, ArtistAnimation and class attribute

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I am trying to code a Conway's game of life in Python and to display the evolution. I have trouble displaying the output. I have pasted my whole code below.

I used this example as a base: [from the matplotlib doc](http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/dynamic_image2.html). My animation is static, but if I use

```
ims.append([plt.imshow(world.state+0, cmap=plt.cm.binary, interpolation='nearest')])
```

it animates correctly. I tried to write a function wolrd.get_state(), thinking it was some kind of evaluation problem, to no avail.

This is driving me nuts, what am I missing here ?

Thanks

```
    import numpy as np
    from scipy.signal import convolve2d

    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib.animation as animation


    class World():
       """world information"""

       def __init__(self, grid):
           # noinspection PyNoneFunctionAssignment
           self.state = np.empty(grid.shape)
           self.__x_size = len(grid[0, :])
           self.__y_size = len(grid[:, 0])
           self.__x = range(self.__x_size)
           self.__y = range(self.__y_size)
           for i in self.__x:
            for j in self.__y:
                self.state[i, j] = grid[i, j]

    def evolve(self):
        alive_neighbours = convolve2d(self.state, np.ones((3, 3)), mode='same', boundary='wrap') - self.state
        for i in self.__y:
            for j in self.__x:
                if alive_neighbours[i, j] < 2:
                    self.state[i, j] = 0
                elif alive_neighbours[i, j] == 3:
                    self.state[i, j] = 1
                elif alive_neighbours[i, j] > 3:
                    self.state[i, j] = 0
        # self.state = np.random.randint(2, size=(self.__x_size, self.__y_size ))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    nbx = 5
    nby = 5
    nb_gen = 5

    initial_seed = np.random.randint(2, size=(nbx, nby))
    world = World(initial_seed)

    ims = []
    fig = plt.figure()

    for i in range(nb_gen):
        ims.append([plt.imshow(world.state, cmap=plt.cm.binary, interpolation='nearest')])
        world.evolve()

    ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval=500, blit=True, repeat_delay=1000)

    plt.show()
```

Note:
I have succesfully used:

```
def animate(i):
    world.evolve()
    return (plt.imshow(world.state, cmap=plt.cm.binary, interpolation='nearest'),)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=nb_gen, interval=500, blit=True, repeat_delay=1000)
```

but this is not what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each frame of the animation is displaying the same world state.

Since the world class only modifies the state, a reference to the *same* object is being passed into imshow() for each frame. Each frame of the animation is referencing the same array.

Matplotlib doesn't draw the animation to the screen until plt.show() is called, so only the final version of the arrays passed into imshow() can be seen, which is the final version of World.state.

This is the same reason that

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a
a.append(4)
print(b)
```

outputs [1, 2, 3, 4]. b points to a, so when a changes, b changes.

Copying the image to be shown fixes the problem.

```
ims.append([plt.imshow(world.state.copy(), cmap=plt.cm.binary, interpolation='nearest')])
```

This is also why world.state + 0 and np.random.randint(2, size=(self.__x_size, self.__y_size )) worked: they both create new arrays, and don't modify the arrays already passed into imshow().

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer. I'm not sure I understand, because, the object is modified right ?
Furthermore, if in the function evolve I uncomment the line "self.state = np.random.randint(2, size=(self.__x_size, self.__y_size ))", then it is animating, ann according to what you say, it is still the same object.

Comment: As I understand it, np.random.randint(2, size=(self.__x_size, self.__y_size )) creates a new array, which means that a new object would be passed in each frame.